# Reading the text file incorrectly in sas

Tags: sas

Problem Statement: I have a text file and I want to read it using SAS INFILE function. But SAS is not giving me the proper output.

```
Text File:
Akash    18 19 20
Tejas       20 16
Shashank 16 20
Meera    18    20
```

The Code that I have tried:

```
DATA Arr;
INFILE "/folders/myfolders/personal/SAS_Array .txt" missover;
INPUT Name$ SAS DS R;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=arr;
RUN;
```

While the result i got is :

```
Table of Contents
Obs Name    SAS DS  R
1   Akash   18  19  20
2   Tejas   20  16  .
3   Shashank16  20  .
4   Meera   18  20  .
```

Which is improper. So what is wrong with the code? I need to read the file in SAS with the same sequence of marks as in text file. Please help.

Expected result:

```
Table of Contents
Obs Name    SAS DS  R
1   Akash   18  19  20
2   Tejas    .  20  16  
3   Shashank16  20  .
4   Meera   18   .  20
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the delimiter in your text file? Are they tabs or spaces? It would also help if you showed what the output _should_ be

Comment: The text file is space delimited. And please check the code i have added the expected output.

Comment: You edited the text file sample in your post. Now it really does not look like it is space-delimited but rather fixed width. Is that right?

Comment: No its space delimited file only and sry i made a mistake while posting the text file.

Comment: Then please post the sample text file correctly. Space-delimited means that values are separated by _a_ space character. In your example, values are delimited by a variable amount of space characters. That is not space delimited. The file as posted here is **fixed width**. If you have a seemingly random number of spaces between values _but_ you have no missing values in your text file, that is still workable with list input. But if values are separated by a variable amount of spaces **and** some values are missing, then there is no way to tell which one is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If that text file is tab-delimited, you should specify the delimiter in the infile statement and use the `dsd` option to account for missing values:

```
DATA Arr;
INFILE "/folders/myfolders/personal/SAS_Array .txt" missover dlm='09'x dsd;
INPUT Name $ SAS DS R;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=arr;
RUN;
```

**EDIT:** after editing, your sample text file now looks fixed-width rather than space-delimited. In that case you should be using column input:

```
DATA Arr;
INFILE "/folders/myfolders/personal/SAS_Array .txt" missover;
INPUT Name $1-9 SAS 10-12 DS 13-15 R 16-18;
RUN;
```

example with datalines:

```
DATA Arr;
INFILE datalines missover;
INPUT Name $1-9 SAS 10-12 DS 13-15 R 16-18;
datalines;
Akash    18 19 20
Tejas       20 16
Shashank 16 20
Meera    18    20
RUN;
```

Comment: The text file is space delimited. Can you give the solution related to it?

Comment: If the values are not in fixed column locations then there is no way to tell which of the three numbers are missing. There is no way to distinguish between the last three records.

Comment: @Tom indeed, like I said in my latest comment on the question. It still would be possible if values were separated by strictly one space, but that is not the case here.

Comment: I think the text file is not space delimited, but is fixed with with spaces making it easier to read.

Comment: @Joe that's my guess also and that's the direction I went with in my edited answer